# Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: java, groovy

I am using Groovy Grail 2.4.4 and JDK 1.7.75

my groovy grail application told me the following error, and I have no idea how to fix them

I have no idea why the service 
    foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor can not be found.

This application has a domain class plugin, and that plugin works fine.

Can some one help me out?

```
    ERROR context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:655)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:765)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:753)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:124)
    ... 25 more
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:655)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:765)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:753)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:124)
    ... 25 more
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: Is foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor actually in your project, or in a plugin that you're including in your BuildConfig?  If it's in a plugin, are you sure that the plugin released correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly mentioned in the error log,

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.everything.services.scheduleexecutor.BillingChargingExecutor
```

Since the required class is not found, you are facing this issue. Please check if this dependency is loaded properly.